# The student involvement question looks like a list question to me, why shouldn't it be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-broad

[In what ways can students get involved in Open Source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/811/190)

> What are some other similar programs for students to get started?

This looks like a classic open-ended list question, which are considered too broad in nearly every site on the network.

Why was this reopened, and why shouldn't it be closed again?

Comment: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/110/328

Comment: @overactor Other sites have different expectations, and the creative nature of worldbuilding does not apply here. Even then, worldbuilding does have limits on what it allows. If you want to propose some boundaries for allowed list questions here then please make your suggestions in an answer. This question linked above though is completely unbounded.

Comment: I'm not providing an answer, but rather showing that not every site considers list questions to be inherently bad. That was posted by a community manager who's not really active on worldbuilding by the way.

Comment: The post on worldbuilding meta is written from a general SE perspective by a community manager not involved with worldbuilding. It is every bit as relevant to our site as it is to others, and well worth considering.

Comment: @trichoplax Sure. But the student involvement question is still so open ended and broad.

Answer (score 1):

### List questions are not in themselves bad.

I'm not going to be able to explain this as well as it already has been explained by [Grace Note](http://stackexchange.com/users/102159/grace-note) so I'll just link what [they had to say on the topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/110/328).

So if we now assume that being a list question is not a reason to close in and of itself, what we're left is is the question: "What is this question really asking for and is this type of question a good fit for our site and the SE format in general?"

I would argue that this particular question is answerable within a few paragraphs, based on relevant experience. ([as Will showed](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/894/168)) And is relevant specifically to our target audience. Additionally, the possible answers can be semi-objectively judged and a best answer can be picked by the OP.

What I would like to see in this particular question is some more specifics as to what **exactly** is expected from this program. (I have commented to that effect)

All in all, I see no strong reason to close this particular question or questions like it of reasonable quality.

Comment: Will's answer almost doesn't address the question. It's good, but it doesn't answer what other student programs there are. That's an open ended question which is why I think it should be closed. Wills answer needs a new question!

Comment: @curiousdannii I might agree that the question is a bit unfortunately phrased so that the good question at its core is only implicitly present. But I'd argue it's not bad enough to close.